# Gray screen on VNC

Tags: server, tightvncserver

I installed ubuntu-server on an old computer of mine to use it as a home media server (smb), but now I want to remotely use it from my MacBook. I prefer terminal, but sometimes I need to open a browser and do some work on the machine.

I installed `tightvncserver` on the old computer and started it with `vncserver`. But when I log-in into VNC Viewer on my Mac, it shows a gray screen.

I have installed `ubuntu-desktop` on the old computer.

Here is my `xstartup`

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Also, can you provide me with what to update `xstatup` with if I would have installed `xubuntu-desktop`?

[gray screen on vnc-viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfHDI.png)